# Path Variable in angular JS being applied as Request Parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am having a problem with an angular js resource that I specify.

Here is my code:

//EDIT - here is where it is being called from

```
function StudentService(Student, $http, $q) {

function getById(id) {
    return Student.query({id: id}).$promise;
}
}

function Students($resource) {
    return $resource('api/students/:id', {id: '@id', version: '    @version'}, {
         get: {method: 'get', timeout: 10000},
         query: {
             url: 'api/school/:id/students',
             method: 'get',
             isArray: true,
            timeout: 10000
    }
});
}
```

I am overwriting the url for the query method, as shown and the path that I want is: (for id=1 for example)
...api/school/1/students

However, this is the url that I get:
...api/school/students?id=1

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is because it is not clear why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: could you please add the usage of the Students resource? Cause this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6xqtvceg/

Comment: Thanks for your help-have updated as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have you seen the fiddle? That seems to work.. Which Angular / ngResource versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help Christiaan-very much appreciated. Everything was right as you identified. I managed to get it working-the issue was that the id parameter being passed to the resource must be named the same at both sides ie: must be named id when passed from the service to the resource. I had it named studentId. This still passes it through but the resource picks it up as ?id=... instead of /{id}/ when this is the case.